# Why does libmill have a limited number of coroutines and context switches per second?

Tags: c, concurrency, hardware

I'm reading up on [`libmill`](http://libmill.org/index.html), and it's written on the landing page that "It can execute up to 20 million coroutines and 50 million context switches per second."

While this is impressive, why even include this number? Wouldn't these numbers vary with the type of hardware the library is being used on? If the limitation is imposed by the library or the language, why would such a limitation exist?

Comment: Probably it's just the result of some random benchmark the library creator ran on his machine, to give an idea of the kind of performance to expect from the library.

Comment: I am fully with you, the numbers seem a bit senseless. As the tutorial.html says: "Enjoy your time with the library and send any questions you may have to libmill@freelists.org". You can just do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more boasting and not a serious constraint. What most likely happened is that they ran some sort of benchmark on a machine and are now advertising that fact. Much more akin to

> "Look! We made it so you can even execute 20 million coroutines and 50
>   million context switches per second! Impressive, huh?"

rather than

> "We have this technical limitation that says you can only execute 20
>   million coroutines and 50 million context switches per second."

That you seem to have read into it :)

Comment: yes that's correct. i ran that benchmark in this PR: https://github.com/sustrik/libmill/pull/39 and since then i've seen better perf